# Copy data from a table to another in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm new in Excel and I have a little problem.
I have a table with some names and their age, names are sorted alphabetically, and I have another table with same names, but they're random, and what I want is to copy the age from the first table to this second table for every name. The thing is that I can't with copy paste, because when I have 1000 names in my table.

[image: picture example]

As you can see, I want to copy the numbers from the first table from "Venit" to column "Venit februarie" for every name in the column "Nume".
Any solution?

Comment: Yes, but how is this setup? It helps to know, are these two books or are they on the same book? We can use the lookup function to find it the names that matches.

Comment: Same book, yea maybe, but i cant use the function for every cell, i need something for all cells to take automatically the numbers from the first table and put in the second.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that these are in the same sheet itself we will use this command.

```
=LOOKUP(H4,$B$3:$B$12,$D$3:D$12)
```

Explanation:

```
LOOKUP(lookup_value,lookup_vector,result_vector)
```

The lookup_value just mean what are we looking for? What cell or static input are we going to reference?

loopup_vector just means from what **SINGLE** column **OR SINGLE** row will we use? What cells are we going to use?

result_vector means **IF** we find a matching value, what the location of that data should we pull from?

UPDATE:
This formula was designed for you to paste into I4 and drag and drop the formula in the other cells.

Comment: One more thing, how should i use formula for all cells? I mean not for every cell but for all instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @RobertRobby `Lookup` requires the lookup vector to be sorted (as your sample data is) and returns a nearest match.  It will be better to use `VLookup(H4, $B4:$D12, 3,0)` it does not require sorted data, and will return exact match only

Comment: @chrisneilsen & matt : Both of those solutions will not work if there are duplicate "nume" entries.  For example, if there are 3 people with the last name "NELU", both formulas will only return the value corresponding to the final entry of  "NELU".  This would result in 3 duplicate values at the second table, omitting 2 of the required matches from the first table.

Comment: @Enteleform, that is true, but without some unique value attached to one of those names, there is no way to know which one he wants. I think how you downvoted it was not correct, because I cannot sort something without a unique value nor indexed. That is something he will have to do on the user end, however I should of informed him of that and I did not think of that when I did do the post.

Comment: @Matt I actually didn't vote on this, just posted my previous comment as an informative statement.  Although there aren't any unique values to reference, it could probably be improved to disregard "Venit" values that have already been pulled which match the "NUME" value in the answer table.  However, even that would have an issue if encountering mutliple "NUME" values which also have a matching "Venit" value.  Honestly, I'm not too sure why a duplicate set of data is necessary here.  Personally, I'd go with a single table & set up some comboboxes with AutoFilter VBA.